# what does __rcu stands for in linux?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am new to linux kernel. My question is about the `task_struct`.
I know that Each `task_struct` has a reference to its parent process via a pointer to the `task_struct` of the parent.

After looking at the sched.h in the `task_struct` definition I noticed the following :

```
struct task_struct __rcu *real_parent; /* real parent process */
```

I found that it is referenced to compiler.h. I guess that  the "__rcu" stands for "read copy update"

Can someone clarify the syntax ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Read-copy-update** is an algorithm that enables concurrent access to readers of a data structure without having to lock the structure. It can be read about [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update).

If the kernel is built with the `CONFIG_SPARSE_RCU_POINTER` config option, `__rcu` is defined in `include/linux/compiler.h` as

```
# define __rcu          __attribute__((noderef, address_space(4)))
```

This is an annotation for a the [Sparse](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/dev-tools/sparse.html) code analysis tool that can warn about certain things the programmer may have overlooked. How this is relevant to RCU is explained in `Documentation/RCU/checklist.txt`:

> __rcu sparse checks: tag the pointer to the RCU-protected data
> structure with __rcu, and sparse will warn you if you
> access that pointer without the services of one of the
> variants of rcu_dereference().

`rcu_dereference()` returns a pointer that can be safely dereferenced by the code and documents the programmer's intention to protect the pointer with the RCU mechanism, enabling tools like Sparse to check for programming errors and omissions.

Answer (score 6):

RCU stands for "read, copy, update". It is an algorithm that allows multiple readers to access data which can be updated or even deleted at the same time by writers.

Under RCU, writers still have to ensure mutual exclusion with regard to one another, but readers do not acquire a lock. Care has to be taken that the shared data structure is updated in ways that do not violate read integrity. If something has to be removed or deleted, the unlinking of that item from the data structure can be done in parallel with the readers but the actual deletion of the memory has to wait until the last reader has finished.

Rather than making the readers acquire a lock, the whereabouts of the readers are inferred in other ways. Threads can announce their intent to browse the data structure by joining a "read side critical section" which is not really a lock but a kind of global phase.

For instance, suppose that some threads entered the RCU read side critical section in phase 0. An updater has performed a deletion and want to free a piece of memory. It has to simply wait for all threads in the system to vacate phase 0. In the meanwhile, other readers are looking at the data structure already, but when they declare their intent to RCU, they do so by entering the RCU read-side critical section under phase 1. Only the phase 0 threads can possibly still have a pointer to the object that was deleted, and so when the last thread leaves phase 0, the object can safely be deleted. Newly arriving threads in phase 1 do not see the object, because the object has been removed from the data structure, so they have no way to find it.

RCU takes advantage of the idea that we do not need lock objects that are "owned" in order to know information like "no thread can be accessing this object any more".

Comment: does rcu need to lock when RCU phase 0 is changing to phase 1?